# Linq to Entities, Table per Type and Nullable Foreign Key Relationships

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, table-per-type

I'm using Linq to entities applying a [Table per Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc765425.aspx) approach. This has been going very well, up to now. I have the following setup:

- Parent Table
- Child Table (Inherits
  from parent)
- Grand Child Table
  (Inherits from Child Table)
- Linking Table (Has Foreign Key Nullable, to Child Table)

Here is the database diagram

[image]

Following the above video i applied the Table Per Type approach to the default schema that Linq to entities creates when you add the above tables to a model.

Before applying Table per Type:

[image]

After Table per Type:

[image]

I then compiled the project and got the error you can see in the image above. To fix this i went to the mapping for the foreign key link, i added the childid field, which the error message was moaning about.

[image]

I then recompiled and get another error:

> Problem in Mapping Fragments starting
>   at lines 147, 176: Two entities with
>   different keys are mapped to the same
>   row. Ensure these two mapping
>   fragments do not map two groups of
>   entities with overlapping keys to the
>   same group of rows.

This is the point i'm at now. The problem seems to the that the "ChildID" on the "LinkingTable" is Nullable. If i set it to be Not nullable i don't get the above error.

I have saved the Database and project used in the above steps to a [sky drive](http://skkurg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pTY9oTppW7UIrkJnml3yfFNfoUGR7SQqEBbSEqrDiJlaD4GPKsxLipKLhzEsEZ3T22vHecn2Lc5QyhFF75KMOTg/TablePerType.zip?download).

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Dave

**Here's the fixed Code (Thanks to The Gecko)**

Before

```
<AssociationSetMapping Name="FK_LinkingTable_Child"
    TypeName="TablePerTypeModel.FK_LinkingTable_Child" 
    StoreEntitySet="LinkingTable">
    <EndProperty Name="Child">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="ChildID" />
    </EndProperty>
    <EndProperty Name="LinkingTable">
        <ScalarProperty Name="LinkTableID" ColumnName="LinkTableID" />
    </EndProperty>
</AssociationSetMapping>
```

After

```
<AssociationSetMapping Name="FK_LinkingTable_Child"
    TypeName="TablePerTypeModel.FK_LinkingTable_Child" 
    StoreEntitySet="LinkingTable">
    <EndProperty Name="Child">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="ChildID" />
    </EndProperty>
    <EndProperty Name="LinkingTable">
        <ScalarProperty Name="LinkTableID" ColumnName="LinkTableID" />
    </EndProperty>
    <Condition ColumnName="ChildID" IsNull="false"/>
</AssociationSetMapping>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try updating the AssociationMapping node in the Mapping section of your EDMX file to include a condition to allow for nulls.

e.g.

```
<AssociationSetMapping>
  ...
  <Condition ColumnName="" IsNull="false"/>
</AssociationSetMapping>
```

Comment: brilliant... that totally works.. It now looks like this:
<Condition ColumnName="ChildID" IsNull="false"/>